# docker cp permissions are wrong when you mount the directory back into container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to grab the `/var/lib/mysql` directory out of a running mysql container in order to keep it for persistence.  Yet when I then mount the directory as a volume mysql complains that it does not have permission:

`mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-02-29 13:34:19 1 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.`

and

`2016-02-29 13:34:20 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-02-29 13:34:20 1 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist`

`` docker cp `cat mysqlinitCID`:/var/lib/mysql   datadir/ ``

at this point I'm even using the tar form of docker cp in combination with `-p` flag to preserve permissions, yet it still comes in with privilege issues.

`` docker cp `cat mysqlinitCID`:/var/lib/mysql  - |sudo tar -C datadir/mysql/ -pxf - ``

It seems like the only way to do this properly is go around `docker cp` and mount say `/tmp` and tar up `/var/lib/mysql` yourself and copying the tarball to the mounted point and get it out that way.

Is there a proper way to utilize `docker cp` that I am missing out on?

I initialize the mysql container like this to grab from:

`docker run \
        --name=$(NAME)-mysql-init \
        -d \
        --env='DB_NAME=$(DB_NAME)' \
        --cidfile="mysqlinitCID" \
        --env='MYSQL_USER=$(DB_USER)' --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASS)" \
        --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASS)" \
        --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=$(DB_NAME)" \
        mysql:5.6`

and here is how I start the container with volume attached:

`docker run \
        --name=$(NAME)-mysql \
        -d \
        --env='DB_NAME=$(DB_NAME)' \
        --cidfile="mysqlCID" \
        --env='MYSQL_USER=$(DB_USER)' --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASS)" \
        --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASS)" \
        --volume=$(MYSQL_DATADIR):/var/lib/mysql \
        mysql:5.6`

Comment: I've got a recipe here that is where my question came from: https://github.com/joshuacox/mkRedmine    `make mysqlinit`, then `make mysqlgrab` and finally `make mysqlrun` to duplicate the above results

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my issue here was a simple typo where I put a mysql directory inside another mysql directory, so the correct answer is to use the tar form with one slight modification above:

`` docker cp `cat mysqlinitCID`:/var/lib/mysql  - |sudo tar -C datadir/ -pxf - ``